# angular-l10n taking translation based on parameter

Tags: angular, localization, l10n.js

I have different notations for specific words based on the notation the client uses, e.g. one client uses the word *Vehicle*, whereas the other uses the word *Car* for the same thing.

I would like to have these notations in the same *resource* files for angular-l10n, like:

```
{
notation1_automobile: Car,
notation2_automobile: Vehicle
}
```

Whether the logged client uses notation1 or notation2 is get from the server.

Do I need to create a custom translation provider or translation handler in this case?

Comment: Is [this pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nSelectPipe) what you are looking for?

Comment: since there's a lot of these different words for different notations I would like to have a global solution. I would have to call this every time on one of those words...